# How to send email/phone number verification code in Django?

Tags: django, web, django-models, backend, verification

I'm building a registeration portal for my website. I'm using Django. Any user needs to input unique username and email to register. How to enable email verification?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Do you mean email verification as in, you send the user an email, or do you mean to verify the email is unique? You mention both.

Comment: Yes. Like when a username enters his email a verification mail will be sent to his inbox.

Answer (score -1):

If you are asking about verification link inside the email that your app is going to send after users registration then maybe check this [link](https://medium.com/@frfahim/django-registration-with-confirmation-email-bb5da011e4ef)